# Not able to click child in expanded listview when i use constraint layout whereas with linear layout it works properly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview, android-constraintlayout, onitemclicklistener

I had copied the code for expanded list view from somewhere on stack and it work properly, i was able to expand the list and click both parent and child, But when i added the check_box element to the layout the child view click does not work any more.
    Please help me with this, its very odd as i am just adding one check-box element.

```
// does not work with when check box element is there
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandedListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
            android:text="Available"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/expandedListItem"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/expandedListItem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/expandedListItem"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/available"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/expandedListItem"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.829"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


//Here is the activity part where click methods have been written.
 expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Expanded1", "Expanded");
                }
            });

            expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    Log.d("Child Clicked", "Child Clicked");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " -> "
                                    + expandableListDetail.get(`enter code here`
                                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("itemName", expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition)  ));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("available", "N"));
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    jParser.hitURL(url, params);
                    Log.d("Update Stock-1", "Update");

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

CLicking the child view item should have been working in both cases, But in presence of check-box click on child is not even being recognized, the method expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener is not even being called....

Comment: okay i found one more thing that the click on child view is not working because of the check_Box element ( Not because of constraint layout), now can anyone suggest a way that i can have the check box and child item view both as clickable and working.

Comment: and also i have edited the question as well.

Comment: Add `android:focusable="false"` for the `CheckBox`

Comment: Thanks a lot John, It worked like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `android:focusable="false"` for the `CheckBox`

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/available"
    android:focusable="false"
      ....
 />
```